# Update MySQL 5.7 to MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, database, upgrade, ubuntu-18.04

I just updated my MySQL 5.7 database to MySQL 8.0

The MySQL documentation says :

> The MySQL server always restarts after an update by APT. Prior to
>   MySQL 8.0.16, run mysql_upgrade after the server restarts to check and
>   possibly resolve any incompatibilities between the old data and the
>   upgraded software. mysql_upgrade also performs other functions; see
>   mysql_upgrade — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables for details. As of
>   MySQL 8.0.16, this step is not required, as the server performs all
>   tasks previously handled by mysql_upgrade.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-upgrade.html

If I connect to MySQL and type the command :

```
mysql_upgrade
```

It displays :

```
->
```

Nothing happens, why ?

[image]

Comment: MySQL does like terminator

Comment: So in other words add a ; and press enter again.

Comment: @ewramner it does not work `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql_upgrade' at line 1`

Answer (score 3):

This command must be run in your shell, not inside MySQL terminal

Comment: are you sure `mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'ubuntu'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.`

Comment: It is actually covered in the document you linked to. It is a shell command and you need to provide options for root login to the database. Read the document in detail before you proceed so that you don't lose data!